# How to simplify a button using a boolean?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have these 2 inputs (buttons)

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="close()">Close</button>
    <input *ngIf="!isEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addCustomer(myForm)" value='Add data'>
    <input *ngIf="isEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-success"  (click)="updateCustomer(myForm)" value='Update'>
 </div>
```

where if **isEdit** is false then I want to show the button "Add data" else I want to show the button "Update" but I wonder if there's a way to simplify this a bit more rather than using 2 inputs for each. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else` capability was added somewhat recently; that's probably why most documentation doesn't have it (yet). But you can write this way:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="close()">Close</button>
  <input *ngIf="!isEdit; else update" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addCustomer(myForm)" value='Add data'>
</div>
<ng-template #update>
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-success"  (click)="updateCustomer(myForm)" value='Update'>
</ng-template>
```

It works; but I don't know how much better it is compared to what you have.